# Elegant Python function to convert CamelCase to snake_case?

Tags: python, camelcasing

Example:

```
>>> convert('CamelCase')
'camel_case'
```

Comment: To convert in the other direction, see this [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303492/how-can-i-simplify-this-conversion-from-underscore-to-camelcase-in-python) stackoverflow question.

Comment: n.b. that's `NotCamelCase` but `thisIs`

Comment: @MattRichards It is a matter of dispute. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase#Variations_and_synonyms)

Comment: @MattRichards For example in Java they use both, CamelCase is used for naming Class definitions, while camelCase is used for naming initialized variables.

Answer (score 1187, accepted):

### Camel case to snake case

```py
import re

name = 'CamelCaseName'
name = re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', '_', name).lower()
print(name)  # camel_case_name
```

If you do this many times and the above is slow, compile the regex beforehand:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])')
name = pattern.sub('_', name).lower()
```

To handle more advanced cases specially (this is not reversible anymore):

```py
def camel_to_snake(name):
    name = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', name).lower()

print(camel_to_snake('camel2_camel2_case'))  # camel2_camel2_case
print(camel_to_snake('getHTTPResponseCode'))  # get_http_response_code
print(camel_to_snake('HTTPResponseCodeXYZ'))  # http_response_code_xyz
```

To add also cases with two underscores or more:

```py
def to_snake_case(name):
    name = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    name = re.sub('__([A-Z])', r'_\1', name)
    name = re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', name)
    return name.lower()
```

### Snake case to pascal case

```py
name = 'snake_case_name'
name = ''.join(word.title() for word in name.split('_'))
print(name)  # SnakeCaseName
```

Comment: This solution fails in these cases: _test_Method, __test__Method, _Test, getHTTPresponseCode, __CamelCase, and _Camel_Case.

Comment: @freegnu, Fails how? It appears to work for me for all of those examples.

Comment: how about the reverse? Convert a `not_camel_case` to `notCamelCase` and/or `NotCamelCase`?

Comment: To avoid double underscores when converting e.g. camel_Case, add this line: `s2.replace('__', '_')`

Comment: Small fix: put `$` at the beginning of the first pattern so it won't prepend `_` at the begninning like so `"Document" -> "_document"`

Comment: Just updated your first regex to match 's' for plural form. It enables you to convert floatingIPsAdresses to floating_ips_addresses instead of floating_i_ps_addresses. Hope it can help :p   =>  re.compile('(.)([A-Z](?!s[A-Z])[a-z]+)')

Comment: Note this is not very reversible. getHTTPResponseCode should convert to get_h_t_t_p_response_code. getHttpResponseCode should convert to get_http_response_code

Comment: Seems to be working flawlessly. Only if there was some explanation given for it....

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi The first regex handles the edge case of an acronym followed by another word (e.g. "HTTPResponse" -> "HTTP_Response") OR the more normal case of an initial lowercase word followed by a capitalized word (e.g. "getResponse" -> "get_Response". The second regex handles the normal case of two non-acronyms (e.g. "ResponseCode" -> "Response_Code") followed by a final call to lowercase everything. Thus "getHTTPResponseCode" -> "getHTTP_ResponseCode" -> "get_HTTP_Response_Code" -> "get_http_response_code"

Comment: `convert = lambda name: re.sub('((?!^)(?<!_)[A-Z][a-z]+|(?<=[a-z0-9])[A-Z])', r'_\1', name).lower()`  - This handles freegnu's cases correctly.

Comment: Nice code, but why not do it the Pythonic way? Use a library! http://stackoverflow.com/a/17328907/1450294

Comment: In PEP8 standard, class names must be the CapWords convention.  So what if we only want to replace phrases if they start with lowercase, as in "x = CamelCase(numberFive + numberSix)" becomes "x = CamelCase(number_five + number_six)".  I'm kind of thinking of doing a regex that matches first letter lowercase followed by letters/digits/underscore, then on this regex call your convert() function like: re.sub("\\b([a-z]\w+)", convert(r"\1"), "x = CamelCase(numberFive + numberSix)").  But this doesn't work even though convert("numberFive") works.

Comment: **train case** would be much better than **snake case**, IMHO – unless you are a snake lover. (Sorry for commenting here, comments to the question are disabled)

Comment: `APIKey` => `a_p_i_key`

Comment: def to_snake(camel_input):
        camel_input = camel_input.replace('&', '_and_')
        camel_input = re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', '_', camel_input).lower()
        words = re.findall(r'[A-Z]?[a-z]+|[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]|\d|\W|$)|\d+', camel_input)
        return '_'.join(words)

Comment: Although this is very old question, its worth pointing out this accepted answer is not even producing camel case - its producing pascal case as capatalising first char.

Comment: Real camelCase implementation: ''.join(word.title() if index_word > 0 else word for index_word, word in enumerate(name.split('_')))

Comment: Real **camelCase** implementation: `''.join(word.title() if index_word > 0 else word for index_word, word in enumerate(name.split('_')))`

Comment: I was looking for a similar solution, to convert strings like RetainUIDs, but this solution seems to fail as `camel_to_snake('RetainUIDs')` returns retain_ui_ds instead of the expected retain_uids

Comment: What about from `ISOCurrencyCode` to `iso_currency_code`?

Comment: Why don't use pydash (https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Answer (score 305):

There's an [inflection library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflection) in the package index that can handle these things for you. In this case, you'd be looking for [`inflection.underscore()`](http://inflection.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#inflection.underscore):

```
>>> inflection.underscore('CamelCase')
'camel_case'
```

Comment: I dont understand why people are up voting the use of custom functions when there is a great library that performs this task. We should not be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @oden Maybe because adding an **entire new dependency** to do the job of a single-line function is fragile over-kill?

Comment: For one instance, sure it's overkill. Across a larger application, no need to reinvent and obfuscate the wheel.

Comment: Regexes back a lot into a "single line", which is why it's lot more than one line with proper testing.

Comment: I'm not sure it works great, it doesn't capture all variations: 'TotalWeight': 840.0,
 'TrackingNumber': '',
 'Vendor': 'NONE',
 'address1': 'du mail',
 'address2': '',
 'address3': '',

Comment: @CecilCurry: I'm sure you're a great programmer, but I'm not sure there aren't cases that you haven't considered—just look at other answers here for examples. That's why I'll always choose a library, because it's the sum experience of many more devs than just me.

Comment: @MichaelScheper You can always just copy the `inflection` library code: `re.sub(r"([a-z\d])([A-Z])", r'\1_\2', re.sub(r"([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])", r'\1_\2', word)).replace("-", "_").lower()` https://inflection.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/inflection.html#underscore

Comment: @MichaelScheper No offense intended. It was an attempt at a compromise: Use the wisdom of the community, and not get more dependencies than necessary. On a side note, you might consider not using idioms like "why on earth". [It can be interpreted as unfriendly](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: @AndréC.Andersen: No offence intended nor taken, but I am truly baffled by the lengths some people are willing to go to avoid an 80kB library. The reasons may be obvious enough for them to consider sarcastic boldface appropriate (see above), but they're not obvious to me, hence the idiom. A big part of the power of Python is the range of libraries available, and in my many years of writing Python applications on a half-dozen platforms, I've never discovered any disadvantage for using them (except a few 'problem' ones, but the inflection library isn't one). I just want to understand the motive.

Comment: @MichaelScheper There are many reasons you might want to limit the number of dependencies. One is bloat, but isn't really a strong argument seeing as it was a small library. Another is dependency [conflicts, etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell#Problems). Last time I experienced this was with Airflow insisting on using an old version of Jinja2. I think there is a balance to these things. IMO a one-liner upvoted by 613 people on SO is not worth creating another dependency for. But, this is no science, some things comes down to preference.

Comment: @AndréC.Andersen: That's a fair argument in general, and I've had to deal with a couple of problem libraries too. I've just also had to fix a lot of bugs caused by people reinventing the wheel. I don't have anything further to add, except that I'm sorry if anybody was offended by my earlier comment. I don't think it was out of step with the tone created earlier, though. Anyhow, thanks.

Comment: I feel you on the "reinventing the wheel" problem. Also, don't worry about the idiom thing, I didn't see it in context of other commenters. Have a nice one.

Comment: @oden a sufficiently upvoted Python answer on StackOveflow is indistinguishable from a library.

Comment: It has been 3 years since up voting this answer and commenting that it is the best solution, I now feel differently. We are now mindful of adding in new libraries to our codebase and would prefer a custom function for many of the reasons stated above. Maintaining a codebase over many years makes you think differently then writing disposable code or code that someone else lives with...

Comment: @oden you could just copy paste the entire library, which is [a single file](https://github.com/jpvanhal/inflection/blob/master/inflection.py) into your code base, which is slightly better than copy pasting an answer from stack overflow and never updating. If it makes you feel better, the library also hasn't been updated since 2015.

Comment: Is it really about the pros and cons of a "one liner" vs. "importing a library"? What about if you need this "one liner" in your code again (and again)? You'll probably start defining (and calling) a function which won't be a "one liner" anymore. And if you need it in different modules (or packages) you'll probably start creating a utils module or package yourself. In those cases I'd tend to consider using a proven library. Specially  when converting to e.g. snakecase in your code also needs a converse function to the original case the (camel case, pascal case etc.).

Comment: Inflection has 0 external dependencies.

Comment: @oden mainly because every third-party module is a code/security risk. Secondly because of the possible added overhead/dependencies. Thirdly because of the ease of adaption/modification to slightly different use-cases.

Answer (score 159):

I don't know why these are all so complicating.

for most cases, the simple expression `([A-Z]+)` will do the trick

```
>>> re.sub('([A-Z]+)', r'_\1','CamelCase').lower()
'_camel_case'  
>>> re.sub('([A-Z]+)', r'_\1','camelCase').lower()
'camel_case'
>>> re.sub('([A-Z]+)', r'_\1','camel2Case2').lower()
'camel2_case2'
>>> re.sub('([A-Z]+)', r'_\1','camelCamelCase').lower()
'camel_camel_case'
>>> re.sub('([A-Z]+)', r'_\1','getHTTPResponseCode').lower()
'get_httpresponse_code'
```

To ignore the first character simply add look behind `(?!^)`

```
>>> re.sub('(?!^)([A-Z]+)', r'_\1','CamelCase').lower()
'camel_case'
>>> re.sub('(?!^)([A-Z]+)', r'_\1','CamelCamelCase').lower()
'camel_camel_case'
>>> re.sub('(?!^)([A-Z]+)', r'_\1','Camel2Camel2Case').lower()
'camel2_camel2_case'
>>> re.sub('(?!^)([A-Z]+)', r'_\1','getHTTPResponseCode').lower()
'get_httpresponse_code'
```

If you want to separate ALLCaps to all_caps and expect numbers in your string you still don't need to do two separate runs just use `|` This expression `((?<=[a-z0-9])[A-Z]|(?!^)[A-Z](?=[a-z]))` can handle just about every scenario in the book

```
>>> a = re.compile('((?<=[a-z0-9])[A-Z]|(?!^)[A-Z](?=[a-z]))')
>>> a.sub(r'_\1', 'getHTTPResponseCode').lower()
'get_http_response_code'
>>> a.sub(r'_\1', 'get2HTTPResponseCode').lower()
'get2_http_response_code'
>>> a.sub(r'_\1', 'get2HTTPResponse123Code').lower()
'get2_http_response123_code'
>>> a.sub(r'_\1', 'HTTPResponseCode').lower()
'http_response_code'
>>> a.sub(r'_\1', 'HTTPResponseCodeXYZ').lower()
'http_response_code_xyz'
```

It all depends on what you want so use the solution that best suits your needs as it should not be overly complicated.

nJoy!

Comment: The last iteration is the most clever, IMO. It took me a little bit to understand that it's only replacing the single character at the beginning of each word -- and that was only because the approach was different than one I'd come up with myself. Nicely done.

Comment: I was puzzled by the `(?!^)` expression being called a look-behind. Unless I'm missing something, what we really want here is a negative look-behind which should be expressed as `(?<!^)`. For reasons I cannot understand your negative look-ahead `(?!^)` seems to work, too...

Comment: This doesn't handle preexisting underscores well:
`"Camel2WARNING_Case_CASE"` becomes `"camel2_warning_case__case"`.
You can add a `(?<!_)` negative lookbehind, to solve it:
     
    
`re.sub('((?<=[a-z0-9])[A-Z]|(?!^)(?<!_)[A-Z](?=[a-z]))', r'_\1', "Camel2WARNING_Case_CASE").lower()`    
returns 
`'camel2_warning_case_case'`

Comment: @Apteryx You're right, `(?!^)` was incorrectly called a "look behind" and should have instead been called a _negative lookahead assertion_. As [this nice explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/7232335) shows, negative lookaheads usually come _after_ the expression you're searching for. So you can think of `(?!^)` as "find `''` where `<start of string>` does not follow". Indeed, a negative lookbehind also works: you can think of `(?<!^)` as "find `''` where `<start of string>` does not precede".

Answer (score 99):

Avoiding libraries and regular expressions:

```py
def camel_to_snake(s):
    return \
        ''.join(
            [ '_'+c.lower() if c.isupper() else c for c in s ]
        ).lstrip('_')
```

```py
>>> camel_to_snake('ThisIsMyString')
'this_is_my_string'
```

Or, if you prefer a functional approach. (Note this converts `HTML` to `h_t_m_l`. See below if you don't want that.

```py
def camelcase_to_snake_case(s):
    
    def substitute_character(index_character):
        (index, c) = index_character

        if c.isupper() and index != 0:
            return '_' + c.lower()
        elif c.isupper():
            return c.lower()
        else:
            return c

    return (
        ''.join(
            map(
                substitute_character,
                enumerate(s),
            )
        )
    )
```

If you want `HTML` to be translated to `Html`, you need a bit of extra functional magic:

```
def camelcase_to_snake_case(s):

    def substitute_character(index_tuple: tuple[int, tuple[bool, str]]):
        (index, flag_tuple) = index_tuple
        (previous_uppercase_flag, c) = flag_tuple

        if previous_uppercase_flag:
            return c.lower()
        elif c.isupper() and index != 0:
            return '_' + c.lower()
        # Optimized out because of the prepended `A` character
        #elif c.isupper():
        #    return c.lower()
        else:
            return c

    def prepend_one(s: str) -> str:
        return 'A' + s

    def sequential_uppercase(character_pair) -> tuple[bool, bool]:
        (c1, c2) = character_pair
        return (c1.isupper() and c2.isupper(), c2)

    return (
        ''.join(
            map(
                substitute_character,
                enumerate(
                    map(
                        sequential_uppercase,
                        pairwise(prepend_one(s)),
                    )
                ),
            )
        )
    )
```

Some test cases for this:

```py
def test_camelcase_to_snake_case():

    test_input_1 = 'UpperCaseCamelCase'
    expected_output = 'upper_case_camel_case'
    test_output = camelcase_to_snake_case(test_input_1)
    assert expected_output == test_output, f'test 1 failed: {test_output}'

    test_input_2 = 'aCamelCaseString'
    expected_output = 'a_camel_case_string'
    test_output = camelcase_to_snake_case(test_input_2)
    assert expected_output == test_output, f'test 2 failed: {test_output}'

    test_input_3 = 'alowercasestring'
    expected_output = 'alowercasestring'
    test_output = camelcase_to_snake_case(test_input_3)
    assert expected_output == test_output, f'test 3 failed: {test_output}'

    test_input_4 = 'snake_case_string'
    expected_output = 'snake_case_string'
    test_output = camelcase_to_snake_case(test_input_4)
    assert expected_output == test_output, f'test 4 failed: {test_output}'
```

and an extra test case for `HTML`

```
def test_camelcase_to_snake_case():

    test_input_5 = 'HTML'
    expected_output = 'html'
    test_output = camelcase_to_snake_case(test_input_5)
    assert expected_output == test_output, f'test 5 failed: {test_output}'
```

Comment: This is the most compact one which avoids using the `re` library and doing the stuff only in one line only using built-in str.methods! It is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28774760/2648551), but avoids using slicing and additional `if ... else` by simply stripping potentially added "_" as first character. I like this most.

Comment: For accepted answer `6.81 µs ± 22.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)` but for this response `2.51 µs ± 25.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)` which is 2.5x times faster! Love this!

Comment: this will convert acronyms like "MultinomialNB" to "multinomal_n_b" instead of "multinomial_nb.

Comment: URL -> u_r_l,  HTTP -> h_t_t_p  (I realize I'm piling on a bit here but ...)

Comment: @WBAR it might be faster but there are tons of case it doesn't handle... examples: `HIThereHOWIsItGoing, how_are_YoU_TeST`. Though I agree it does do regular camel case to snake case well enough

Comment: @rv.kvetch how do you propose "HIThereHOWIsItGoing" could be turned from camel case to snake case? That is not in any sensible format.

Comment: Fair point, maybe something like "hiThereHOWIsItGoing" which I believe should be camel case.

Comment: Here are a few adaptations to make it a bit more general:

`lambda string: "".join(char if not char.isupper() else ("" if i and (substr := string[i-1] + (next_char or "")) == substr.upper() else "_") + char.lower() for i, (char, next_char) in enumerate(zip(string, [*string[1:], None]))).lstrip("_")`. This update is submitted as a lambda function since we cannot add newlines in this comment section.

Works fine for cases like `"HelloWorld"`, `HelloSTACKOverflow`, and `HelloSTACKOverflowOMG` when using python 3.10+

Answer (score 44):

[stringcase](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stringcase) is my go-to library for this; e.g.:

```
>>> from stringcase import pascalcase, snakecase
>>> snakecase('FooBarBaz')
'foo_bar_baz'
>>> pascalcase('foo_bar_baz')
'FooBarBaz'
```

Comment: For `hello world` it will add double  `_` as `hello__world` that is not good

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia this is incorrect: `stringcase.snakecase('hello world')` returns `'hello_world'` (one underscore)

Comment: sorry, if the string is `hello  world`  it will add double `_`

Comment: it's up to the user to pass correct arguments to the library :)

Comment: Sometimes the user doesn't have control over the input of functions. Robust libraries could handle better.

Comment: double underscores are commonly used in Python; your "better" is someone else's "worse"; if you want a library with different semantics you can use one; your criticism is not part of the original question which is about CamelCase, not spaces

Answer (score 14):

I think this solution is more straightforward than previous answers:

```
import re

def convert (camel_input):
    words = re.findall(r'[A-Z]?[a-z]+|[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]|\d|\W|$)|\d+', camel_input)
    return '_'.join(map(str.lower, words))


# Let's test it
test_strings = [
    'CamelCase',
    'camelCamelCase',
    'Camel2Camel2Case',
    'getHTTPResponseCode',
    'get200HTTPResponseCode',
    'getHTTP200ResponseCode',
    'HTTPResponseCode',
    'ResponseHTTP',
    'ResponseHTTP2',
    'Fun?!awesome',
    'Fun?!Awesome',
    '10CoolDudes',
    '20coolDudes'
]
for test_string in test_strings:
    print(convert(test_string))
```

Which outputs:

```
camel_case
camel_camel_case
camel_2_camel_2_case
get_http_response_code
get_200_http_response_code
get_http_200_response_code
http_response_code
response_http
response_http_2
fun_awesome
fun_awesome
10_cool_dudes
20_cool_dudes
```

The regular expression matches three patterns:

1. `[A-Z]?[a-z]+`: Consecutive lower-case letters that optionally start with an upper-case letter.
2. `[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]|\d|\W|$)`: Two or more consecutive upper-case letters. It uses a lookahead to exclude the last upper-case letter if it is followed by a lower-case letter.
3. `\d+`: Consecutive numbers.

By using `re.findall` we get a list of individual "words" that can be converted to lower-case and joined with underscores.

Comment: There is a good example here to get the Numerics tokenized independantly.

Comment: Broken: convert("aB") -> 'a'

Comment: @adw This regex covers that case: `r"[A-Z]?[a-z]+|[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]|\d|\W|$)|\d+|[A-Z]{2,}|[A-Z]$"`

Comment: this works and it's actually the fastest version i could find in this thread tbh. the version in the comments supports all remaining edge cases too i think.

Comment: actually, I spoke too soon. does anyone know a regex that can handle words like `H@Y`, `H@y`, `WhaTSuP!`, or `B!KE`?

Comment: I found my fix. It looks like I just needed to remove the last `$` in the comment above. Also, this version handles words with numbers, like `t3st` or special cases with leading numbers, like `1nfinity` which was something I needed to account for in my code. The reason is that this last case isn't a valid identifier in python. Here's the regex to cover these edge cases: `r'\d[A-Z]+|[A-Z]?[a-z\d]+|[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]|\d|\W|$)|\d+|[A-Z]{2,}|[A-Z]'`

Answer (score 8):

Personally I am not sure how anything using regular expressions in python can be described as elegant. Most answers here are just doing "code golf" type RE tricks. Elegant coding is supposed to be easily understood.

```
def to_snake_case(not_snake_case):
    final = ''
    for i in xrange(len(not_snake_case)):
        item = not_snake_case[i]
        if i < len(not_snake_case) - 1:
            next_char_will_be_underscored = (
                not_snake_case[i+1] == "_" or
                not_snake_case[i+1] == " " or
                not_snake_case[i+1].isupper()
            )
        if (item == " " or item == "_") and next_char_will_be_underscored:
            continue
        elif (item == " " or item == "_"):
            final += "_"
        elif item.isupper():
            final += "_"+item.lower()
        else:
            final += item
    if final[0] == "_":
        final = final[1:]
    return final

>>> to_snake_case("RegularExpressionsAreFunky")
'regular_expressions_are_funky'

>>> to_snake_case("RegularExpressionsAre Funky")
'regular_expressions_are_funky'

>>> to_snake_case("RegularExpressionsAre_Funky")
'regular_expressions_are_funky'
```

Comment: `+=` on strings is almost always a bad idea. Append to a list and `''.join()` it in the end. Or in this case, simply join it with an underscore...

Comment: How is a single-line regular expression _not_ innately superior in just about every practical way (including readability) to inefficient multi-line character iteration and brute-force string munging? Python provides regular expression support out-of-the-box for a reason.

Comment: regular expression are **good** but I think that when we can do a simple function to replace it, it's better.

Comment: @CecilCurry - Regular expressions are VERY complex.  See the compiler and parser that Python uses: https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/sre_compile.py & https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/sre_parse.py -- Simple string manipulation like this likely much faster than an RE doing the same.

Comment: +1. Regexes can be a real CPU sink, and on intensive calculations will dramatically lower your performances. For simple tasks, always prefer simple functions.

Comment: "For simple tasks, always prefer simple functions" is definitely good advice, but this answer is neither a simple function nor an elegant one. Regex might be slower, but defaulting to a complicated function like this (that is ALSO untested and has numerous potential points of error) is completely premature optimization

Comment: I'm sorry but this function is very hard to read compared to a simple regex.

Comment: Down-voted this answer because it is not at elegant or sophisticated; rather verbose and not performant.  I am not sure why the author says... "Elegant coding is supposed to be easily understood."  The code uses bad practices like "+=" operators for strings.  Also, xrange() is from Python 2.7, which was retired in January 2020.

Answer (score 7):

```
''.join('_'+c.lower() if c.isupper() else c for c in "DeathToCamelCase").strip('_')
re.sub("(.)([A-Z])", r'\1_\2', 'DeathToCamelCase').lower()
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution:

```
def un_camel(text):
    """ Converts a CamelCase name into an under_score name. 

        >>> un_camel('CamelCase')
        'camel_case'
        >>> un_camel('getHTTPResponseCode')
        'get_http_response_code'
    """
    result = []
    pos = 0
    while pos < len(text):
        if text[pos].isupper():
            if pos-1 > 0 and text[pos-1].islower() or pos-1 > 0 and \
            pos+1 < len(text) and text[pos+1].islower():
                result.append("_%s" % text[pos].lower())
            else:
                result.append(text[pos].lower())
        else:
            result.append(text[pos])
        pos += 1
    return "".join(result)
```

It supports those corner cases discussed in the comments. For instance, it'll convert `getHTTPResponseCode` to `get_http_response_code` like it should.

Comment: -1 because this is very complicated compared to using regexps.

Comment: EOL, I'm sure plenty of non-regexp people would think otherwise.

Comment: This solution fails in these cases: __Method, _test_Method_, __test__Method, getHTTPrespnseCode, __get_HTTPresponseCode, _Camel_Case, _Test, and _test_Method.

Comment: @Evan, those people would be bad programmers.

Answer (score 4):

I don't get idea why using both .sub() calls? :) I'm not regex guru, but I simplified function to this one, which is suitable for my certain needs, I just needed a solution to convert camelCasedVars from POST request to vars_with_underscore:

```
def myFunc(...):
  return re.sub('(.)([A-Z]{1})', r'\1_\2', "iTriedToWriteNicely").lower()
```

It does not work with such names like getHTTPResponse, cause I heard it is bad naming convention (should be like getHttpResponse, it's obviously, that it's much easier memorize this form).

Comment: I forgot to mention, that '{1}' is not needed, but sometimes it help clarify some mist.

Comment: -1: this just doesn't work. Try with for example with `'HTTPConnectionFactory'`, your code produces `'h_tt_pconnection_factory'`, code from accepted answer produces `'http_connection_factory'`

Answer (score 4):

Using regexes may be the shortest, but this solution is way more readable:

```
def to_snake_case(s):
    snake = "".join(["_"+c.lower() if c.isupper() else c for c in s])
    return snake[1:] if snake.startswith("_") else snake
```

Comment: @blueyed that's completely unrelated, this question has nothing to do with django.

Comment: It's just an example, like HTTPResponseCode, which is handled by http://stackoverflow.com/a/23561109/15690.

Answer (score 3):

**For the fun of it:**

```
>>> def un_camel(input):
...     output = [input[0].lower()]
...     for c in input[1:]:
...             if c in ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'):
...                     output.append('_')
...                     output.append(c.lower())
...             else:
...                     output.append(c)
...     return str.join('', output)
...
>>> un_camel("camel_case")
'camel_case'
>>> un_camel("CamelCase")
'camel_case'
```

Or, more for the fun of it:

```
>>> un_camel = lambda i: i[0].lower() + str.join('', ("_" + c.lower() if c in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" else c for c in i[1:]))
>>> un_camel("camel_case")
'camel_case'
>>> un_camel("CamelCase")
'camel_case'
```

Comment: c.isupper() rather than c in ABCEF...Z

Comment: Python doesn't have regexes?  A quick 's/[a-z]\K([A-Z][a-z])/_\L$1/g; lc $_' in Perl does the job (although it does not handle getHTTPResponseCode well; but that's expected, that should be named getHttpResponseCode)

Comment: `str.join` has been deprecated for _ages_.  Use `''.join(..)` instead.

Comment: jrockway: It does have regular expressions, via the "re" module. It shouldn't be too difficult to make this work using regex rather than the approaches posted here.

Comment: Python noob here, but why return str.join('', output)? Just to create a copy?

Comment: Tarks, `output` is a list of characters, not a string. So running it through str.join with an empty string as the first parameter will compress the list into a string.

Comment: @John: Why do you say that is deprecated?  str.join("", []) is exactly the same as calling "".join([]).  Bound vs. unbound.  Same as calling ParentClass.__init__(self).  However, I find the first more readable.  Can you point to any docs on the depreciation?

Comment: I like this approach, but why go via a list when you can just build the output as a string?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a elegant method, is a very 'low level' implementation of a simple state machine (bitfield state machine), possibly the most anti pythonic mode to resolve this,  however re module also implements a too complex state machine to resolve this simple task, so i think this is a good solution.

```
def splitSymbol(s):
    si, ci, state = 0, 0, 0 # start_index, current_index 
    '''
        state bits:
        0: no yields
        1: lower yields
        2: lower yields - 1
        4: upper yields
        8: digit yields
        16: other yields
        32 : upper sequence mark
    '''
    for c in s:

        if c.islower():
            if state & 1:
                yield s[si:ci]
                si = ci
            elif state & 2:
                yield s[si:ci - 1]
                si = ci - 1
            state = 4 | 8 | 16
            ci += 1

        elif c.isupper():
            if state & 4:
                yield s[si:ci]
                si = ci
            if state & 32:
                state = 2 | 8 | 16 | 32
            else:
                state = 8 | 16 | 32

            ci += 1

        elif c.isdigit():
            if state & 8:
                yield s[si:ci]
                si = ci
            state = 1 | 4 | 16
            ci += 1

        else:
            if state & 16:
                yield s[si:ci]
            state = 0
            ci += 1  # eat ci
            si = ci   
        print(' : ', c, bin(state))
    if state:
        yield s[si:ci] 


def camelcaseToUnderscore(s):
    return '_'.join(splitSymbol(s))
```

splitsymbol can parses all case types: UpperSEQUENCEInterleaved, under_score, BIG_SYMBOLS and cammelCasedMethods

I hope it is useful

Comment: Hideous, but it runs about 3x faster than the regex method on my machine. :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the excellent Schematics lib

https://github.com/schematics/schematics

It allows you to created typed data structures that can serialize/deserialize from python to Javascript flavour, eg:

```
class MapPrice(Model):
    price_before_vat = DecimalType(serialized_name='priceBeforeVat')
    vat_rate = DecimalType(serialized_name='vatRate')
    vat = DecimalType()
    total_price = DecimalType(serialized_name='totalPrice')
```

Answer (score 2):

So many complicated methods...
Just find all "Titled" group and join its lower cased variant with underscore.

```
>>> import re
>>> def camel_to_snake(string):
...     groups = re.findall('([A-z0-9][a-z]*)', string)
...     return '_'.join([i.lower() for i in groups])
...
>>> camel_to_snake('ABCPingPongByTheWay2KWhereIsOurBorderlands3???')
'a_b_c_ping_pong_by_the_way_2_k_where_is_our_borderlands_3'
```

If you don't want make numbers like first character of group or separate group - you can use `([A-z][a-z0-9]*)` mask.

Answer (score 1):

A horrendous example using regular expressions (you could *easily* clean this up :) ):

```
def f(s):
    return s.group(1).lower() + "_" + s.group(2).lower()

p = re.compile("([A-Z]+[a-z]+)([A-Z]?)")
print p.sub(f, "CamelCase")
print p.sub(f, "getHTTPResponseCode")
```

Works for getHTTPResponseCode though!

Alternatively, using lambda:

```
p = re.compile("([A-Z]+[a-z]+)([A-Z]?)")
print p.sub(lambda x: x.group(1).lower() + "_" + x.group(2).lower(), "CamelCase")
print p.sub(lambda x: x.group(1).lower() + "_" + x.group(2).lower(), "getHTTPResponseCode")
```

EDIT: It should also be pretty easy to see that there's room for improvement for cases like "Test", because the underscore is unconditionally inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Very nice RegEx proposed on [this site](http://jason.diamond.name/weblog/2009/08/15/splitting-camelcase-with-regular-expressions/comment-page-1/):

```
(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])
```

If python have a String Split method, it should work...

In Java:

```java
String s = "loremIpsum";
words = s.split("(?&#60;!^)(?=[A-Z])");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the Python regular expression module doesn't (as of version 3.6) support splitting on zero-length matches.

Answer (score 1):

This simple method should do the job:

```
import re

def convert(name):
    return re.sub(r'([A-Z]*)([A-Z][a-z]+)', lambda x: (x.group(1) + '_' if x.group(1) else '') + x.group(2) + '_', name).rstrip('_').lower()
```

- We look for capital letters that are precedeed by any number of (or zero) capital letters, and followed by any number of lowercase characters.
- An underscore is placed just before the occurence of the last capital letter found in the group, and one can be placed before that capital letter in case it is preceded by other capital letters.
- If there are trailing underscores, remove those.
- Finally, the whole result string is changed to lower case.

(taken from [here](http://rodic.fr/blog/camelcase-and-snake_case-strings-conversion-with-python/), see [working example online](http://ideone.com/JyVkds))

Comment: This is an answer for the opposite question (how to convert *to* camel case).

Answer (score 1):

Lightely adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/users/267781/matth
who use generators.

```
def uncamelize(s):
    buff, l = '', []
    for ltr in s:
        if ltr.isupper():
            if buff:
                l.append(buff)
                buff = ''
        buff += ltr
    l.append(buff)
    return '_'.join(l).lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow I just stole this from django snippets. ref http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/585/

Pretty elegant

```
camelcase_to_underscore = lambda str: re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]|[A-Z](?=[^A-Z])', r'_\g<0>', str).lower().strip('_')
```

Example:

```
camelcase_to_underscore('ThisUser')
```

Returns:

```
'this_user'
```

[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/J3kmSl/2)

Comment: Bad form using str as a local variable name.

Comment: This fails miserably if there are any underscores at the beginning or end of a string and if there are any underscores before a capital letter.

Comment: doesnt take into account numbers 

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I did to change the headers on a tab-delimited file. I'm omitting the part where I only edited the first line of the file. You could adapt it to Python pretty easily with the re library. This also includes separating out numbers (but keeps the digits together). I did it in two steps because that was easier than telling it not to put an underscore at the start of a line or tab.

Step One...find uppercase letters or integers preceded by lowercase letters, and precede them with an underscore:

Search:

```
([a-z]+)([A-Z]|[0-9]+)
```

Replacement:

```
\1_\l\2/
```

Step Two...take the above and run it again to convert all caps to lowercase:

Search:

```
([A-Z])
```

Replacement (that's backslash, lowercase L, backslash, one):

```
\l\1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to the same problem, except that I needed a chain; e.g.

```
"CamelCamelCamelCase" -> "Camel-camel-camel-case"
```

Starting from the nice two-word solutions here, I came up with the following:

```
"-".join(x.group(1).lower() if x.group(2) is None else x.group(1) \
         for x in re.finditer("((^.[^A-Z]+)|([A-Z][^A-Z]+))", "stringToSplit"))
```

Most of the complicated logic is to avoid lowercasing the first word.  Here's a simpler version if you don't mind altering the first word:

```
"-".join(x.group(1).lower() for x in re.finditer("(^[^A-Z]+|[A-Z][^A-Z]+)", "stringToSplit"))
```

Of course, you can pre-compile the regular expressions or join with underscore instead of hyphen, as discussed in the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Concise without regular expressions, but HTTPResponseCode=> httpresponse_code:

```
def from_camel(name):
    """
    ThisIsCamelCase ==> this_is_camel_case
    """
    name = name.replace("_", "")
    _cas = lambda _x : [_i.isupper() for _i in _x]
    seq = zip(_cas(name[1:-1]), _cas(name[2:]))
    ss = [_x + 1 for _x, (_i, _j) in enumerate(seq) if (_i, _j) == (False, True)]
    return "".join([ch + "_" if _x in ss else ch for _x, ch in numerate(name.lower())])
```

Comment: `from_camel('removes_underscore')` -> `'removesunderscore'`

Answer (score 0):

Without any library :

```
def camelify(out):
    return (''.join(["_"+x.lower() if i<len(out)-1 and x.isupper() and out[i+1].islower()
         else x.lower()+"_" if i<len(out)-1 and x.islower() and out[i+1].isupper()
         else x.lower() for i,x in enumerate(list(out))])).lstrip('_').replace('__','_')
```

A bit heavy, but

```
CamelCamelCamelCase ->  camel_camel_camel_case
HTTPRequest         ->  http_request
GetHTTPRequest      ->  get_http_request
getHTTPRequest      ->  get_http_request
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs to transform a complete source file, here is a script that will do it.

```
# Copy and paste your camel case code in the string below
camelCaseCode ="""
    cv2.Matx33d ComputeZoomMatrix(const cv2.Point2d & zoomCenter, double zoomRatio)
    {
      auto mat = cv2.Matx33d::eye();
      mat(0, 0) = zoomRatio;
      mat(1, 1) = zoomRatio;
      mat(0, 2) = zoomCenter.x * (1. - zoomRatio);
      mat(1, 2) = zoomCenter.y * (1. - zoomRatio);
      return mat;
    }
"""

import re
def snake_case(name):
    s1 = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s1).lower()

def lines(str):
    return str.split("\n")

def unlines(lst):
    return "\n".join(lst)

def words(str):
    return str.split(" ")

def unwords(lst):
    return " ".join(lst)

def map_partial(function):
    return lambda values : [  function(v) for v in values]

import functools
def compose(*functions):
    return functools.reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)), functions, lambda x: x)

snake_case_code = compose(
    unlines ,
    map_partial(unwords),
    map_partial(map_partial(snake_case)),
    map_partial(words),
    lines
)
print(snake_case_code(camelCaseCode))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use [Google's (nearly) deterministic Camel case algorithm](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming-camel-case-defined), then one does not need to handle things like `HTMLDocument` since it should be `HtmlDocument`, then this regex based approach is simple. It replace all capitals or numbers with an underscore. Note does not handle multi digit numbers.

```py
import re

def to_snake_case(camel_str):
    return re.sub('([A-Z0-9])', r'_\1', camel_str).lower().lstrip('_')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def convert(name):
    return reduce(
        lambda x, y: x + ('_' if y.isupper() else '') + y, 
        name
    ).lower()
```

And if we need to cover a case with already-un-cameled input:

```
def convert(name):
    return reduce(
        lambda x, y: x + ('_' if y.isupper() and not x.endswith('_') else '') + y, 
        name
    ).lower()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def convert(camel_str):
    temp_list = []
    for letter in camel_str:
        if letter.islower():
            temp_list.append(letter)
        else:
            temp_list.append('_')
            temp_list.append(letter)
    result = "".join(temp_list)
    return result.lower()
```

Answer (score -5):

Use: `str.capitalize()` to convert first letter of the string (contained in variable str) to a capital letter and returns the entire string.

Example:
Command: "hello".capitalize() 
Output: Hello

Comment: This isn't related to the question - the OP wants CamelCase -> snake_case, not Capitalization.