# Convert not_camel_case to notCamelCase and/or NotCamelCase in Python?

Tags: python

Basically, the reverse of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/does-the-python-standard-library-have-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-camel-case). Here's my attempt, but it's not working.

```
def titlecase(value):
    s1 = re.sub('(_)([a-z][A-Z][0-9]+)', r'\2'.upper(), value)
    return s1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def titlecase(value):
    return "".join(word.title() for word in value.split("_"))
```

Python is more readable than regex, and easier to fix when it's not doing what you want.

If you want the first letter lowercase as well, I would use a second function that calls the function above to do most of the work, then just lowercases the first letter:

```
def titlecase2(value):
     return value[:1].lower() + titlecase(value)[1:]
```

Comment: Precisely. The regexes were a red herring. Never use a regex for anything before checking whether the methods of a string object will do what you want. In this case, `split` tokenizes the string and `title` conveniently capitalizes a word.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error with your regex. Instead of

```
([a-z][A-Z][0-9]+) # would match 'oN3' but not 'one'
```

use

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+) # matches any alphanumeric word
```

**However**, this also won't work because `r'\2'.upper()` can't be used that way. Instead, try:

```
s1 = re.sub('(_)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', lambda p: p.group(2).capitalize(), value)
```

Answer (score 2):

`@kindall` provide good solution(credit goes to him).
But if you want syntax "myCamel" the first word does not need to be capitalized then you have to change a bit:

```
def titlecase(value):
     rest = value.split("_")
     return rest[0]+"".join(word.title() for word in rest[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

For NotCamelCase, Using a regex or a loop sounds like an overkill.

```
str.title().replace("_", "")
```

Comment: +1 This is a fantastic answer.  The curse of being late to the party.

Answer (score 0):

Like jtbandes said, you should mash the character classes together like

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

The next trick is what you do with the replacement. When you say

```
r'\2'.upper()
```

the upper() actually happens *before* called sub. But you can use another feature of `sub`: you can pass a function to handle the match:

```
re.sub('(_)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', lambda match: match.group(2).capitalize(), value)
```

Now your lambda will get called with the match. Also you can use `subn` to have the replacement happen on more than one place:

```
re.subn('(_)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', lambda match: match.group(2).capitalize(), value)[0]
```