# How to replace uppercase with underscore?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, uppercase

I'm new to Python and I am trying to replace all uppercase-letters within a word to underscores, for example:

```
ThisIsAGoodExample
```

should become

```
this_is_a_good_example
```

Any ideas/tips/links/tutorials on how to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/does-the-python-standard-library-have-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-camel-case

Comment: The example you give matches neither the title nor the description of this question. Are you trying to replace all uppercase characters with underscores or are you trying to convert CamelCase to lowercase_underscore_separated? You'll find that unless you can explain in words what it is you want to do, solving it in Python (or any other language) is going to be too challenging.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a regex way:

```
import re
example = "ThisIsAGoodExample"
print re.sub( '(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', '_', example ).lower()
```

This is saying, "Find points in the string that *aren't* preceeded by a start of line, and *are* followed by an uppercase character, and substitute an underscore. Then we lower()case the whole thing.

Comment: That misses a lot of uppercase letters. It wouldn't handle one spelling of my name, "Éric", for example. IIRC, `\p{Lu}` is the appropriate pattern, not `[A-Z]`.

Answer (score 12):

```
import re
"_".join(l.lower() for l in re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', 'ThisIsAGoodExample'))
```

EDIT:
Actually, this only works, if the first letter is uppercase. Otherwise this (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/does-the-python-standard-library-have-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-camel-case)) does the right thing:

```
def convert(name):
    s1 = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s1).lower()
```

Comment: Take it easy on the newbie. :)

Comment: this is the best answer!

Answer (score 5):

This generates a list of items, where each item is "_" followed by the lowercased letter if the character was originally an uppercase letter, or the character itself if it wasn't. Then it joins them together into a string and removes any leading underscores that might have been added by the process:

```
print ''.join('_' + char.lower() if char.isupper() else char
              for char in inputstring).lstrip('_')
```

BTW, you haven't specified what to do with underscores that are already present in the string. I wasn't sure how to handle that case so I punted.

Answer (score 2):

```
example = 'ThisIsAGoodExample'
# Don't put an underscore before first character.
new_example = example[0].lower()
for character in example[1:]:
    # Append an underscore if the character is uppercase.
    if character.isupper():
        new_example += '_'
    new_example += character.lower()
```

Comment: Replace line 6 with `if character.isupper()` which (should) handle unicode, too.

Comment: Replace line number 3 to new_example = example[0].lower()

Answer (score 2):

As no-one else has offered a solution using a generator, here's one:

```
>>> sample = "ThisIsAGoodExample"
>>> def upperSplit(data):
...   buff = ''
...   for item in data:
...     if item.isupper():
...       if buff:
...         yield buff
...         buff = ''
...     buff += item
...   yield buff
...
>>> list(upperSplit(sample))
['This', 'Is', 'A', 'Good', 'Example']
>>> "_".join(upperSplit(sample)).lower()
'this_is_a_good_example'
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse your string, each time you encounter an upper case letter, insert an _ before it and then switch the found character to lower case

Comment: What about the first uppercase character?

Comment: @rplnt - Since his verbiage doesn't match his example, I went with verbiage

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Well, he wrote "within a word" which I read as "in the middle of a word".

Comment: He also didn't say anything about converting to lowercase - his verbiage really should have converted ThisIsAGoodExample to _his_s__ood_xample

Answer (score 0):

An attempt at a readable version:

```js
import re

_uppercase_part = re.compile('[A-Z][^A-Z]*')    

def uppercase_to_underscore(name):
    result = ''
    for match in _uppercase_part.finditer(name):
        if match.span()[0] > 0:
            result += '_'
        result += match.group().lower()
    return result
```