# How to convert json data into python object and replace invalid characters in keys such as spaces with valid characters for dot notation access

Tags: python, json, object, namespaces

There is a [good answer](http://How%20to%20convert%20JSON%20data%20into%20a%20Python%20object) to [How to convert JSON data into a Python object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15882054/15446959) but my JSON keys have invalid characters such as spaces and `":"` in key strings.

Question is how to convert them to valid values so dot notation access can be used. For example `{"key: 1":1}` should be replaced with `{"key__1"}` so
`obj.key_1` notation could be used. Note that replacing `" "` an `":"` with `"_"` would make a valid object attribute name from an invalid name.

Answer (score 0):

I found this other answer
[Python recursively replace character in keys of nested dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700705/python-recursively-replace-character-in-keys-of-nested-dictionary)
combining the two, you can access use dot notation to access keys that are not valid names for attributes.
This is the content of test_json.json

```
   [
{"key 1": 1}
,{"key :2": 2}
]
```

And this is the complete processing

```
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace
def convert(k):
    k=k.replace(':',"_")  #replace : with _ since ":" not acceptable in syntax
    k=k.replace("(","_")
    k=k.replace(")","_")
    k=k.replace("/","_")
    return k.replace(' ', '_')  #replace space with underscore in string k

def change_keys(obj, convert):  #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700705/python-recursively-replace-character-in-keys-of-nested-dictionary
    """
    Recursively goes through the dictionary obj and replaces keys with the convert function.
    """
    if isinstance(obj, (str, int, float)):
        return obj
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        new = obj.__class__()
        for k, v in obj.items():
            new[convert(k)] = change_keys(v, convert)
    elif isinstance(obj, (list, set, tuple)):
        new = obj.__class__(change_keys(v, convert) for v in obj)
    else:
        return obj
    return new
 

fpath=r'c:\temp\test_json.json'
with open (fpath) as f:
        x = json.load(f) #object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d)  
        
    xnew=change_keys(x,convert) #get rid of invalid characters spaces, ":", "("...
    xnew=json.loads(json.dumps(xnew),object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d)) #convert to new json data that has no spaces etc in names
```

Then you can use dot notation to access key values since spaces and other special characters have been replaced with "_" above to create valid names
`xnew[0].key_1`