# Python function to convert CamelCCase to camel_c_case?

Tags: python, camelcasing

I've looked over the other threads about camel case, but I couldn't find the answer for this case:

I have -> "AddEEven"

and I want -> "add_e_even"

There are cases when I have -> "AddEven"
and I want -> "add_even"
(This case I know how to do it) I just need a regular expression that covers both cases.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No, it's not, I checked that thread and I did not find the answer for my specific case, that's why I open a new one.

Comment: That's funny because the answer you said it worked has been taken from there

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def convert(name):
    s1 = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s1).lower()
```

See here: [Elegant Python function to convert CamelCase to snake_case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/elegant-python-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-camel-case)