# Javascript convert PascalCase to underscore_case/snake_case

Tags: javascript, string, case-conversion

How can I convert `PascalCase` string into `underscore_case/snake_case` string? I need to convert dots into underscores as well.

eg. convert

```
TypeOfData.AlphaBeta
```

into

```
type_of_data_alpha_beta
```

Comment: Try this link buddy it help you for sure http://jamesroberts.name/blog/2010/02/22/string-functions-for-javascript-trim-to-camel-case-to-dashed-and-to-underscore/

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You could try the below steps.

- Capture all the uppercase letters and also match the preceding optional dot character.
- Then convert the captured uppercase letters to lowercase and then return back to replace function with an `_` as preceding character. This will be achieved by using anonymous function in the replacement part.
- This would replace the starting uppercase letter to `_` + lowercase_letter.
- Finally removing the starting underscore will give you the desired output.

  ```
  var s = 'TypeOfData.AlphaBeta';
  console.log(s.replace(/(?:^|\.?)([A-Z])/g, function (x,y){return "_" + y.toLowerCase()}).replace(/^_/, ""));
  ```

**OR**

```js
var s = 'TypeOfData.AlphaBeta';
alert(s.replace(/\.?([A-Z])/g, function (x,y){return "_" + y.toLowerCase()}).replace(/^_/, ""));
```

> any way to stop it for when a whole word is in uppercase. eg. `MotorRPM` into `motor_rpm` instead of `motor_r_p_m`? or `BatteryAAA` into `battery_aaa` instead of `battery_a_a_a`?

```js
var s = 'MotorRMP';
alert(s.replace(/\.?([A-Z]+)/g, function (x,y){return "_" + y.toLowerCase()}).replace(/^_/, ""));
```

Comment: Thanks, any way to stop it for when a whole word is in uppercase. eg. `MotorRMP` into `motor_rpm` instead of `motor_r_p_m`? or `BatteryAAA` into `battery_aaa` instead of `battery_a_a_a`.

Comment: `alert(s.replace(/\.?([A-Z]+)/g, function (x,y){return "_" + y.toLowerCase()}).replace(/^_/, ""));`

Comment: The above solutions fail with "attributeGUILabel" which should convert to "attribute_gui_label".

Comment: I found a solution that works.. see my answer below

Comment: I would prefer without callback `s.replace(/\.?([A-Z]+)/g, '_$1').toLowerCase().replace(/^_/, "")`

Answer (score 111):

```
str.split(/\.?(?=[A-Z])/).join('_').toLowerCase();
```

u're welcome

```js
var s1 = 'someTextHere';
var s2 = 'SomeTextHere';
var s3 = 'TypeOfData.AlphaBeta';

var o1 = s1.split(/\.?(?=[A-Z])/).join('_').toLowerCase();
var o2 = s2.split(/\.?(?=[A-Z])/).join('_').toLowerCase();
var o3 = s3.split(/\.?(?=[A-Z])/).join('_').toLowerCase();

console.log(o1);
console.log(o2);
console.log(o3);
```

Comment: It does not work with _' SomeTextHere'_ because of the leading whitespace. Adding a `trim` before the `split` solves it.

Answer (score 65):

Alternatively using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#snakeCase):

```
lodash.snakeCase(str);
```

Example:

```
_.snakeCase('TypeOfData.AlphaBeta');
// ➜ 'type_of_data_alpha_beta'
```

Lodash is a fine library to give shortcut to many everyday js tasks.There are many other similar string manipulation functions such as `camelCase`, `kebabCase` etc.

Comment: Wow thanks for this, I was using my own toSnakeCase, toTitleCase(_.startCase), toCamelCase. Thanks to this I now switched to lodash and it works much better then mine! I had no idea lodash had this!

Comment: Also thank you! I use lodash every day and didn't realize it could do this!

Answer (score 12):

## This solution solves the non-trailing acronym issue with the solutions above

I ported the code in [1175208](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/elegant-python-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-snake-case) from Python to JavaScript.

#### Javascript Code

```
function camelToSnakeCase(text) {
    return text.replace(/(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)/, '$1_$2').replace(/([a-z0-9])([A-Z])/, '$1_$2').toLowerCase()
}
```

#### Working Examples:

```
camelToSnakeCase('thisISDifficult') -> this_is_difficult

camelToSnakeCase('thisISNT') -> this_isnt

camelToSnakeCase('somethingEasyLikeThis') -> something_easy_like_this
```

Answer (score 11):

```
"alphaBetaGama".replace(/([A-Z])/g, "_$1").toLowerCase() // alpha_beta_gamma
```

**Problem** - Need to convert a camel-case string ( such as a property name ) into underscore style to meet interface requirements or for meta-programming.

**Explanation**
This line uses a feature of regular expressions where it can return a matched result ( first pair of () is `$1`, second is `$2`, etc ).

Each match in the string is converted to have an underscore ahead of it with `_$1` string provided. At that point the string looks like `alpha_Beta_Gamma`.

To correct the capitalization, the entire string is converted toLowerCase().

Since toLowerCase is a fairly expensive operation, its best not to put it in the looping handler for each match-case, and run it once on the entire string.

After `toLowerCase` it the resulting string is `alpha_beta_gamma` ( in this example )

Answer (score 1):

This will get you pretty far: https://github.com/domchristie/humps

You will probably have to use regex replace to replace the "." with an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54246501/8002564) but I edited it so suit your question.

```js
const camelToSnakeCase = str => str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => `_${letter.toLowerCase()}`).replace(/^_/,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

Good examples for js:

1. Snake Case
2. Kebab Case
3. Camel Case
4. Pascal Case

have [here](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/convert-string-to-different-case-styles-snake-kebab-camel-and-pascal-case-in-javascript-da724b7220d7)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toCamelCase(s) {
  // remove all characters that should not be in a variable name
  // as well underscores an numbers from the beginning of the string
  s = s.replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9_\- ])|^[_0-9]+/g, "").trim().toLowerCase();

  // uppercase letters preceeded by a hyphen or a space
  s = s.replace(/([ -]+)([a-zA-Z0-9])/g, function(a,b,c) {
    return c.toUpperCase();
  });

  // uppercase letters following numbers
  s = s.replace(/([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z])/g, function(a,b,c) {
    return b + c.toUpperCase();
  });

  return s;
}
```

Try this function, hope it helps.

Comment: Isn't it wrong in direction? `CamelToUnderscore` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
"TestString".replace(/[A-Z]/g, val => "_" + val.toLowerCase()).replace(/^_/,"")
```

replaces all uppercase with an underscore and lowercase, then removes the leading underscore.

Answer (score 0):

### A Non-Regex Answer that converts PascalCase to snake_case

**Note:** I understand there are tons of good answers which solve this question elegantly. I was recently working on something similar to this where I chose not to use `regex`. So I felt to answer a `non-regex` solution to this.

```js
const toSnakeCase = (str) => {
    return str.slice(0,1).toLowerCase() + str.split('').slice(1).map((char) => {
        if (char == char.toUpperCase()) return '_' + char.toLowerCase();
        else return char;
    }).join('');
}
```

Eg.

```js
inputString = "ILoveJavascript" passed onto toSnakeCase()
```

would become `"i_love_javascript"`