# How to convert camelCase to snake_case?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to convert a string of that is in camel case to snake case using TypeScript.

Remember that the "snake case" refers to the format style in which each space is replaced by an underscore (_) character and the first letter of each word written in lowercase.

Example: `fieldName` to `field_name` should be a valid conversion, but `FieldName` to `Field_Name` is not valid.

Comment: what have you tried? I'd use a regex to split by an uppercase letter to start with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript convert PascalCase to underscore\_case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521224/javascript-convert-pascalcase-to-underscore-case)

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

```
const camelToSnakeCase = str => str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => `_${letter.toLowerCase()}`);
```

Comment: Its not work when i used Upper camel case to snake case. `ItemName`=`_item_name`

Comment: @Badrul however that is more PascalCase

Comment: ItemName => item_name: ```const camel_to_snake = str => str[0].toLowerCase() + str.slice(1, str.length).replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => `_${letter.toLowerCase()}`);```

Comment: This version is working for upper camel case as well
```str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, (letter, index) => { return index == 0 ? letter.toLowerCase() : '_'+ letter.toLowerCase();});```

Comment: my variant works fine with first uppercased letter:
```text.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join('_').toLowerCase()```

Comment: @EvseevVadim -- that's not camel case then ;)  Also, the question explicitly requests that that not be valid

Comment: @EvseevVadim, you are alright on my book... it is a very good solution, using the positive lookahead... good job! And thanks

Comment: Here's one that works for both camel and pascal: `const camelToSnake = str => str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1_$2').toLowerCase();`

Comment: The provided camelToSnakeCase function doesn't address the issue with the first character being an uppercase letter. It will still insert an underscore before the first uppercase letter, even if it's the first character in the string.

To fix the issue, you can add a replace call at the end to remove any leading underscore:

Answer (score 27):

You could do something like this:

```
function camelToUnderscore(key) {
   var result = key.replace( /([A-Z])/g, " $1" );
   return result.split(' ').join('_').toLowerCase();
}

console.log(camelToUnderscore('itemName'));
```

Comment: Slightly modified version of the code: var result = (value
    .replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/g, '_')
    .replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, " $1")
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
    .trim()
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s/g, '_'));
   if (/^\d/.test(result)) {
    result = "x" + result;
   }

Comment: @abasar what is the advatage of your slightly modified version?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
function toSnakeCase(inputString) {
    return inputString.split('').map((character) => {
        if (character == character.toUpperCase()) {
            return '_' + character.toLowerCase();
        } else {
            return character;
        }
    })
    .join('');
}
// x = item_name
```

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful.

for me, i also added a check to ensure that the new string wont start with an underscore by replacing your `'_'` with `(index != 0 ? '_': '')` and adding index as a parameter to the map function `...map((character, index) => {...`

Comment: I also used the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55521416/ to add an check for alphabet characters to this function so that numbers and symbols (which are the same character after making them uppercase) don't cause this function to just keep doubling the mnumber of underscores when a snake_case string is passed in. However, this also has the flaw of limiting the input to only the hardcoded character set

Answer (score 4):

I have tested with below function and handle most of my cases

```
    function convertToSnakeCase(str) {
      str = str[0].toLowerCase() + str.slice(1, str.length).replace(/[A-Z]/g, letter => `_${letter.toLowerCase()}`);
      str  = str.replaceAll(" _","_")

      return str.replaceAll(" ","_").replace(/(^_*|_*$)/g, '');;
   }
```

Test cases handled

```
convertToSnakeCase("Payas AsdDs asD")
'payas_asd_ds_as_d'

convertToSnakeCase("Payas AsdDs")
'payas_asd_ds'

convertToSnakeCase("Pay  AsdDs")
'pay__asd_ds'

convertToSnakeCase('test_') 
'test';
```

Comment: I think this solution, however, if a string ends with a space (e.g. `test `), it appends `_` (e.g. `test_`), therefore I’d suggest to remove the leading and trailing underscores as the last replacement: `const convertToSnakeCase = s => s.replace(/[A-Z]/g, l => `_${l.toLowerCase()}`).replace(/ +_*/g, '_').replace(/(^_*|_*$)/g, '')`. Also the final test case result (`pay__asd_ds`) is invalid snake_case string, as it contains two consecutive `_` chars

Comment: My test cases: `convertToSnakeCase('Payas AsdDs asD') === 'payas_asd_ds_as_d'; convertToSnakeCase('Payas AsdDs') === 'payas_asd_ds'; convertToSnakeCase('Pay  AsdDs') === 'pay_asd_ds'; convertToSnakeCase('thisIsAnExample') === 'this_is_an_example'; convertToSnakeCase('test_') === 'test';`.

Comment: SO formatting removed the backticks from my previous comment, therefore the following the correct code: ```const convertToSnakeCase = s => s.replace(/[A-Z]/g, l => `_${l.toLowerCase()}`).replace(/ +_*/g, '_').replace(/(^_*|_*$)/g, '')```.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use external libraries, the easiest way might be to use lodash's `_.snakeCase(string)`

Answer (score 2):

Doing some research on the [Regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) area I found there is a cool feature called **positive lookahead**. *(it matches a group after the main expression without including it in the result)*

Previous approaches are prefixing each UPPER char with a `_`, also for the ones in the first position in the string.

So let's fix that up using positive lookahead ;)

```js
function convertCamelToSnake(str){
 return str.replace(/([a-zA-Z])(?=[A-Z])/g,'$1_').toLowerCase()
}

console.log(convertCamelToSnake('camelCaseUrl')) // camel_case_url
console.log(convertCamelToSnake('HereIsABigCamelCaseStr')) // here_is_a_big_camel_case_str
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers solved the problem in exactly the way I want, this is the behaviour i would like:

- applePie -> apple_pie
- ApplePie -> apple_pie
- toISOString -> to_iso_string
- innerHTML -> inner_html

I see it as bad practice to uppercase abbreviations and *toISOString* should rather be cased *toIsoString* - unfortunately the world does not care much about my rules.

And this is the solution I came up with:

```
str.replace(/(([a-z])(?=[A-Z][a-zA-Z])|([A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z]))/g,'$1_').toLowerCase()
```

Thanks to Rene Ricardo for the core idea that my solution also contains.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer will lead with an `_` if the first character is uppercase. This solves the issue.

```
 export function camelToSnake(string = '') {
    return string
      .replace(/([A-Z])/g, (match, group) => `_${group.toLowerCase()}`)
      .replace(/^_/, '');
 }
```

Comment: I think, you don't need to default to `''` twice.