# How can I best optimize my angular function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need your help, I have a code and I need to optimize it, can anyone know how this could be?
This is my code:

```
handlerChangeInfo(value, fieldName: string) {
if (fieldName === 'fullName') {
  this.billingFields.full_name = value;
}
if (fieldName === 'address') {
  this.billingFields.address = value;
}
if (fieldName === 'postalCode') {
  this.billingFields.postal_code = value;
}
if (fieldName === 'city') {
  this.billingFields.city = value;
}
if (fieldName === 'stateOrProvince') {
  this.billingFields.state_or_province = value;
}
if (fieldName === 'taxId') {
  this.billingFields.tax_id = value;
}
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54246477/how-to-convert-camelcase-to-snake-case-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an object to map your field name values to the object key names

```
const obj = {
  fullName: 'full_name',
  address: 'address',
  postalCode: 'postal_code',
  city: 'city',
  stateOrProvince: 'state_or_province',
  taxId: 'tax_id'
}


handlerChangeInfo(value, fieldName: string) {
   if (obj[fieldName]) {
      this.billingFields[obj[fieldName]] = value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map version

```
const obj = new Map([
   ['fullName', 'full_name'],
  ['address', 'address'],
  ['postalCode', 'postal_code'],
  ['city', 'city'],
  ['stateOrProvince', 'state_or_province'],
  ['taxId', 'tax_id']
]);

handlerChangeInfo(value, fieldName: string) {
   if (obj.get(fieldName)) {
      this.billingFields[obj.get(fieldName)] = value;
   }
}
```