# Python: Change uppercase letter

Tags: python, camelcasing

I can't figure out how to replace the second uppercase letter in a string in python.

**for example:**

```
string = "YannickMorin"
```

I want it to become yannick-morin

As of now I can make it all lowercase by doing **string.lower()** but how to put a dash when it finds the second uppercase letter.

Comment: you can use `re` module to `re.sub` all upper-case letters with `-\1` then make everything lower case. or use `re.split` to split at each capital letter then `'-'.join` and then convert to lower case

Comment: Here's a similar one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/elegant-python-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-camel-case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Regex

```
>>> import re
>>> split_res = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', 'YannickMorin')
['Yannick', 'Morin' ]
>>>'-'.join(split_res).lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more a task for regular expressions:

```
result = re.sub(r'[a-z]([A-Z])', r'-\1', inputstring).lower()
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputstring = 'YannickMorin'
>>> re.sub(r'[a-z]([A-Z])', r'-\1', inputstring).lower()
'yannic-morin'
```

Answer (score 1):

Find uppercase letters that are not at the beginning of the word and insert a dash before. Then convert everything to lowercase.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\B([A-Z])', r'-\1', "ThisIsMyText").lower()
'this-is-my-text'
```

Answer (score 0):

the `lower()` method does not change the string in place, it returns the value that either needs to be printed out, or assigned to another variable.  You need to replace it.. One solution is:

```
strAsList = list(string)
strAsList[0] = strAsList[0].lower()
strAsList[7] = strAsList[7].lower()
strAsList.insert(7, '-')
print (''.join(strAsList))
```

Comment: OP wants to convert from TitleCase to dashed-case.