# Golang regexp.ReplaceAllString ignores the replacement string "$X_"

Tags: go

I'm trying to convert CamelCase to snake_case using the regex I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1176023). Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
in := "camelCase"
var re1 = regexp.MustCompile(`(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)`)
out := re1.ReplaceAllString(in, "$1_$2")
```

The regex will match `lCase`. `$1` here is `l` and `$2` is `Case`, so using the replacement string `"$1_$2"` should result in `camel_Case`. Instead, it results in `cameCase`.

Changing the replacement string to `"$1_"` results in `came`. If I change it to `"$1+$2"`, the result will be `camel+Case` as expected ([see playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GemEuXGGxw)).

Right now, my workaround is to use `"$1+$2"` as the replacement string, and then using `strings.Replace` to change the plus sign to an underscore. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix is to use `${1}_$2` (or `${1}_${2}` for symmetry).

Per https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.Expand (my emphasis):

> In the template, a variable is denoted by a substring of the form
>   $name or ${name}, where name is a non-empty sequence of letters,
>   digits, **and underscores**.
>
> ...
>
> In the $name form, name is taken to
>   be as long as possible: $1x is equivalent to ${1x}, not ${1}x, and,
>   $10 is equivalent to ${10}, not ${1}0.

So in `$1_$2`, you're actually looking for a group named `1_` and then another group named `2` and putting them together.

As to why using `$1_$2` (or `$foo$2` for that matter) results in "cameCase," that same documentation says:

> A reference to an out of range or unmatched index or a name that is
>   not present in the regular expression is replaced with an empty slice.

So replacing with `"$1_$2"` is equivalent to replacing with just `"$2"`.