# how can i change string using for-loop without regex in python

Tags: python, lambda

how can i change string using for-loop without regex.

example : (python 2.7.1)

```
import re
trans = lambda src: re.sub("([A-Z])", lambda m:"_"+m.group().lower(), src, flags=0)
print(trans("helloWorld"))
```

i expect to result as :

```
hello_world
```

i want to change from regex version into for-loop version.

conditions

- the result will be the same
- just one line!
- using for loop

Comment: Whenever I see named `lambda`s with embedded `lambda`s, I think "coding competition/challenge." Is that what this is for? If not, I highly recommend against this practice.

Comment: You should avoid trying to do everything in one line… it just leads to unreadable results (and is often downright impossible in Python).

Comment: If you're trying to convert camelCase to underscores, you should probably survey all the answers from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1175208

Comment: You cannot use a real for loop within a single line as a for loop has to be on its own line in Python. You could use a list comprehension in a single line which also uses the `for` keyword but is technically not a for loop. As for actual solutions to your problem, check the linked question; there are a few one-liners in there.

Answer (score 1):

```
def change(string):
    for letter in string:
        if letter.isupper():
            yield '_{}'.format(letter.lower())
        else:
            yield letter

print ''.join(change("helloWorld"))
```

If you want to have it in one line:

```
print ''.join(letter.isupper() and '_{}'.format(letter.lower()) or letter for letter in 'helloWorld')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve it using `list comprehension` (i.e one liner for loop) as:

```
>>> my_string = "helloWorld"
>>> ''.join(['_{}'.format(s.lower()) if s.isupper() else s for s in my_string])
'hello_world'
```

**Explanation:**

List is nothing but a list of chars. Iterate over each char and check whether it is upper case character using `isupper()` fuct. If it is, replace it to `_<lower-case>` using `lower()` func.

The result of above list comprehension is: `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '_w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']`. Join the list to find your string i.e. `hello_world`