# Converting Acronyms in CamelCase to snake_case in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code converts the camelcase to snake case:

```
 def convertToSnakeCase(name):
        s1 = re.sub('(.^_)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
        return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s1).lower()
```

How would I go about converting, where I have 3 consecutive capital letters like ISM but split it like is_my:

ThisISMyTest --------------> This_is_my_test

Comment: What about four consecutive caps? What's the desired output then? How about five?

Comment: @NPE it depends on the size acronym. I'm not sure if it could be done because there isn't a way to tell python the size of the acronym

Comment: _ThisISMyTest_ is not in camel case, is it?

Comment: Yes but I'm trying to convert it to snake case

Comment: Here you find some better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/elegant-python-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-snake-case

Answer (score 1):

There may be a simpler way, but the following worked for me for converting camel to snake case without breaking up acronyms.

```
# Ex. LOLThisIsATest -> lol_this_is_a_test
def camel_to_snake_case(name: string):
    snake_case = name[0]
    for idx in range(1, len(name)-1):
        is_upper = name[idx].isupper()
        followed_by_lower = not name[idx+1].isupper()
        preceded_by_lower = not name[idx-1].isupper()
        if (is_upper and followed_by_lower) or (is_upper and preceded_by_lower):
            snake_case+='_'
        snake_case+=name[idx]
    snake_case+=name[len(name)-1] # append last letter
    return snake_case.lower()

# testing
print("Expected: lol_this_is_a_test")
print("Actual:   " + camel_to_snake_case("LOLThisIsATest"))
```

Answer (score -1):

A little bit of a different approach, and works for the most part. I don't see how you can get around `IS` in `ThisISMyTest` since a program really couldn't tell what's a word without getting into natural language processing.

```
def convertToSnakeCase(name):
  split_name = list(name)
  for c in range(len(split_name)):
    if split_name[c].isupper() and c != 0 and split_name[c-1] != '_':
        split_name.insert(c,'_')
        c +=1

  return ''.join(split_name).lower()

print(convertToSnakeCase("ThisISMyTest"))
```

`this_i_s_my_test`

Comment: Buggy, `ThisISREALLYMYLONGTest` become `this_i_s_r_e_a_l_l_y_mylongtest`