# R gsub regex Pascal Case to Camel Case

Tags: r, regex, string

I want to write a gsub function using R regexes to replace all capital letters in my string with underscore and the lower case variant. In a seperate gsub, I want to replace the first letter with the lowercase variant. The function should do something like this:

```
pascal_to_camel("PaymentDate") -> "payment_date"
pascal_to_camel("AccountsOnFile") -> "accounts_on_file"
pascal_to_camel("LastDateOfReturn") -> "last_date_of_return"
```

The problem is, I don't know how to `tolower` a `"\\1"` returned by the regex.

I have something like this:

```
name_format = function(x) gsub("([A-Z])", paste0("_", tolower("\\1")), gsub("^([A-Z])", tolower("\\1"), x))
```

But it is doing `tolower` on the string `"\\1"` instead of on the matched string.

Comment: search for "lookahead" and "look behind" constructs in regex

Comment: edited to highlight different problem

Comment: the duplicated question is in python. my question is in R.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following solution (converted from Python,  see the [Elegant Python function to convert CamelCase to snake_case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/elegant-python-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-snake-case) post):

```
> pascal_to_camel <- function(x) tolower(gsub("([a-z0-9])([A-Z])", "\\1_\\2", gsub("(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)", "\\1_\\2", x)))
> pascal_to_camel("PaymentDate")
[1] "payment_date"
> pascal_to_camel("AccountsOnFile")
[1] "accounts_on_file"
> pascal_to_camel("LastDateOfReturn")
[1] "last_date_of_return"
```

**Explanation**

- `gsub("(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)", "\\1_\\2", x)` is executed first to insert a `_` between any char followed with an uppercase ASCII letter followed with 1+ ASCII lowercase letters (the output is marked as `y` in the bullet point below)
- `gsub("([a-z0-9])([A-Z])", "\\1_\\2", y)` - inserts `_` between a lowercase ASCII letter or a digit and an uppercase ASCII letter (result is defined as `z` below)
- `tolower(z)` - turns the whole result to lower case.

The same regex with Unicode support (`\p{Lu}` matches any uppercase Unicode letter and `\p{Ll}` matches any Unicode lowercase letter):

```
pascal_to_camel_uni <- function(x) {
     tolower(gsub("([\\p{Ll}0-9])(\\p{Lu})", "\\1_\\2", 
         gsub("(.)(\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+)", "\\1_\\2", x, perl=TRUE), perl=TRUE))
}
pascal_to_camel_uni("ДеньОплаты")
## => [1] "день_оплаты"
```

See [this online R demo](https://ideone.com/earuLU).

Answer (score 1):

Using two regex `([A-Z])` and `(?!^[A-Z])([A-Z])`, `perl = TRUE`, `\\L\\1` and `_\\L\\1`:

```
name_format <- function(x) gsub("([A-Z])", perl = TRUE, "\\L\\1", gsub("(?!^[A-Z])([A-Z])", perl = TRUE, "_\\L\\1", x))
> name_format("PaymentDate")
[1] "payment_date"
> name_format("AccountsOnFile")
[1] "accounts_on_file"
> name_format("LastDateOfReturn")
[1] "last_date_of_return"
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/uav06F)