# Issue with SQLAlchemy - Marshmallow nested object inferring foreign key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get Marshmallow-SQLAlchemy to deserialize an object with a nested object without specifying the foreign key for the nested object (which should be the primary key of the parent object). Here's a standalone example:

```python
# Python version == 3.8.2
from datetime import datetime
import re

# SQLAlchemy == 1.3.23
from sqlalchemy import func, create_engine, Column, ForeignKey, Text, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker

# marshmallow==3.10.0
# marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.24.2
from marshmallow import fields
from marshmallow.fields import Nested
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema

################################################################################
# Set up
################################################################################

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///test.db")

Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()


################################################################################
# Models
################################################################################

@as_declarative()
class Base(object):

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        # From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/elegant-python-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-snake-case
        name = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', cls.__name__)
        return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', name).lower()

    @declared_attr
    def updated(cls):
        return Column(DateTime, default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now(), nullable=False)


class Account(Base):
    id = Column(Text, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    tags = relationship("AccountTag", backref="account")


class AccountTag(Base):
    account_id = Column(Text, ForeignKey('account.id'), primary_key=True)
    Key = Column(Text, primary_key=True)
    Value = Column(Text, nullable=False)


################################################################################
# Schemas
################################################################################

class AutoSchemaWithUpdate(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        load_instance = True
        sqla_session = session
    updated = fields.DateTime(default=lambda: datetime.now())


class AccountSchema(AutoSchemaWithUpdate):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        include_relationships = True

    tags = Nested("AccountTagSchema", many=True)


class AccountTagSchema(AutoSchemaWithUpdate):
    class Meta:
        model = AccountTag
        include_fk = True


################################################################################
# Test
################################################################################

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

account_object = AccountSchema().load({
        "id": "ABC1234567",
        "name": "Account Name",
        "tags": [
            {
                "Value": "Color",
                "Key": "Blue"
            }
        ]
    })

session.merge(account_object)

session.commit()
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 88, in <module>
    account_object = AccountSchema().load({
  File "C:\python\site-packages\marshmallow_sqlalchemy\schema\load_instance_mixin.py", line 92, in load
    return super().load(data, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\site-packages\marshmallow\schema.py", line 727, in load
    return self._do_load(
  File "C:\python\site-packages\marshmallow\schema.py", line 909, in _do_load
    raise exc
marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'tags': {0: {'account_id': ['Missing data for required field.']}}}
```

I feel like I'm trying to do something intuitive but I'm not sure anymore. I'm sure that I'm close here but am having no luck getting this to work. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting the error because you've specified `include_fk` in the `Meta` class for `AccountTagSchema`.

You can inspect the fields that have been generated for the schema:

```py
print(AccountTagSchema._declared_fields["account_id"])
# <fields.String(default=<marshmallow.missing>, attribute=None, validate=[], required=True, load_only=False, dump_only=False, missing=<marshmallow.missing>, allow_none=False, error_messages={'required': 'Missing data for required field.', 'null': 'Field may not be null.', 'validator_failed': 'Invalid value.', 'invalid': 'Not a valid string.', 'invalid_utf8': 'Not a valid utf-8 string.'})>
```

Notice that it generates `account_id` with `required=True`, this is due to the sqlalchemy column that it represents being `NOT NULL` as it is part of the primary key.

So the simplest thing is to remove `include_fk` from the schema meta:

```py
class AccountTagSchema(AutoSchemaWithUpdate):
    class Meta(AutoSchemaWithUpdate.Meta):
        model = AccountTag
        #  include_fk = True  <--- remove
```

...however, run the script and you'll run into another problem:

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.dict' is not mapped

This means that we end up passing a `dict` to SQLAlchemy session where it is expecting a mapped `Base` subclass.

The reason for this is that when a child class inherits from a base schema, e.g., `AutoSchemaWithUpdate` in this case, the child class does not automatically inherit the parent's meta configuration. The docs provide [a couple of strategies for this](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#base-schema-i), the simplest being that the child's `Meta` class should also inherit from the parent's `Meta` class:

```py
class AccountSchema(AutoSchemaWithUpdate):
    class Meta(AutoSchemaWithUpdate.Meta):  # <--- this here
        model = Account
        include_relationships = True

    tags = Nested("AccountTagSchema", many=True)
```

Once we do that for both `AccountSchema` and `AccountTagSchema` we are ready to run the script again and it works...the first time. Immediately run the script again, and another error occurs:

> AssertionError: Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key column 'account_tag.account_id' on instance '<AccountTag at 0x7f14b0f9b670>'

This is a consequence of the design decision to have the loaded `AccountTag` instances unidentifiable (i.e., excluding the primary key from the payload) and the decision to include the foreign key field as part of the primary key for `AccountTag`.

SQLAlchemy cannot identify that the newly created `AccountTag` instances are the same as the ones that already exist, so it first tries to disassociate the original account tags from the account by setting the value of the foreign key field to `None`. However, this isn't allowed as the foreign key is also the primary key and cannot be set NULL.

The solution for this is described [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/cascades.html#delete-orphan) and involves setting an explicit `cascade` on the `relationship`:

```py
class Account(Base):
    id = Column(Text, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    tags = relationship("AccountTag", backref="account", cascade="all,delete-orphan")
```

Now run the script again, and it will work every time.

Comment: 1000x yes. Thank you for the THOROUGH explanation, great insight, and (ultimately) for helping me get this working. This is more informative / clear than the actual docs for what I imagine is an edge case / unintended use of the modules.

Comment: You're welcome, I agree that the docs are a bit sparse in some areas for this library, but as always with open source, it takes motivated individuals, with time to step up and improve these things!