# Convert a "camelCasing" to a "camel_casing"

Tags: python, string, list, loops

So I've written a code which does that but can't seem to convert this `thisDoesAThing` to `this_does_a_thing` but rather giving an output like this `thisDoesA_thing`
So help me please
This is my code:

```
import string
test = input("Enter your camelCasing")
loop = 1
x = string.ascii_uppercase
m = list(x)
for i in m:
  while True:
    while i in test and loop < 2:
      loop +=1
      n = i.lower()
      j = test.replace(i,"_"+n)
      print(j)
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1176023/13124794) answers your question.

Comment: why python2.7 tag when it looks like you use python3? Why 3 nested loops, especially the infinite `while True`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the algo for you to implement. Note no nested loops are necessary

```
let output be an empty string

for each symbol in input

   if symbol is uppercase
       unless this is a first symbol, append '_' to the output
       convert symbol to lower case

   append symbol to the output
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat similar implementation of the algorithm in python suggested by @gog

```
test = input("Enter your camelCasing")
ans=''
for i in range(len(test)):
    if test[i].isupper():
        if i==0:
            ans+=test[i].lower()
        else:
            ans+="_"+test[i].lower()
    else:
        ans+=test[i]
        
print(ans)
```