# How to convert camel case into snake case in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Take a string from the user which is written in camel case and then convert it into snake case.

I tried using isupper method to find the uppercase letters in the string but unable to separate them.

Comment: Please show your attempts. And see [ask]

Comment: Also, does this answer your question? [Elegant Python function to convert CamelCase to snake\_case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/elegant-python-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-snake-case)

Answer (score 1):

```
s=input()
''.join(['_'+c.lower() if c.isupper() else c for c in s]).lstrip('_')
```

Or you can install `inflection` library

```
pip install inflection
```

then:

```
import inflection
inflection.underscore('MyNameIsTalha')
#'my_name_is_talha'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def camel_to_snake(camel_string):
return ''.join(['_' + ch.lower() if i > 0 and ch.isupper() else ch.lower() for i, ch in enumerate(camel_string)])
```

Example :

```
snake_string = camel_to_snake("C4melCa5eString")
print(snake_string)  # Output: "c4mel_ca5e_string"
```

Answer (score 0):

def camel_to_snake(camel_string):
return ''.join(['_' + ch.lower() if i > 0 and ch.isupper() else ch.lower() for i, ch in enumerate(camel_string)])