# Get a dictionary of related model values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model `Post` with some fields. Aside from that I have some models which have `Post` as a `ForeignKey`.

Some examples are:

```
class ViewType(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="view_types",
        verbose_name=_("Post"),
    )
    view = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=VIEW_TYPE_CHOICES, verbose_name=_("View")
    )
    ...

class HeatType(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="heat_types",
        verbose_name=_("Post"),
    )
    heat = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, choices=HEAT_TYPE_CHOICES, verbose_name=_("Heat")
    )
    ...
```

So what I want to do here is somehow get a dictionary with all the values of those fields in my view. For example instead of doing this for all of the models that have `Post` as a `ForeignKey`:

```
heat_type = HeatType.objects.filter(post=post)
view_type = ViewType.objects.filter(post=post)

dict = {
   "view_type": view_type.view,
   "heat_type": heat_type.heat,
   etc...
}
```

get all the relevant related fields in one go. Is there a simpler solution for that? Or do I have to manually get all queries for each model?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some trepidation....

```
class Post(models.Model):
    def dump(self):
        mydict = {}

        for k, v in Post.__dict__.items():
            # find the attributes that represent the reverse foreign keys
            if type(v) == ReverseManyToOneDescriptor:
                print(k)
                mydict[k] = getattr(self, k).all()

        print(mydict)
```

With that solution, each value in `mydict` has a list of *instances*, but not the values of `heat` and `view` respectively.  What you might do is add a methods to `HeatType` and `ViewType` that have the same name, like so

```
class ViewType(models.Model):
    def dump(self):
        return self.view

class HeatType(models.Model):
    def dump(self):
        return self.view
```

Now you can dump each related object into `mydict()` with

```
            if type(v) == ReverseManyToOneDescriptor:
                print(k)
                mydict[k] = [instance.dump() for instance in getattr(self, k).all()]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about defining a function with input as `["heat", "view"]` plus the post’s primary key `post_pk` and output the dictionary you wanted.

This code is half-tested but you get the idea:

```python
def snake_to_camel(string):
    return ''.join(word.title() for word in string.split('_'))

def get_dictionary(list_prefixes, post_pk):
    d = {}
    for prefix in list_prefixes:
        camel = snake_to_camel(prefix) + "Type"
        d[prefix + "_type"] = eval(f'{camel}.objects.filter(post={post_pk}).{prefix}')
    return d
```

And then you call it like:

```python
get_dictionary(["heat", "view"], post)
```

Source: [camelcasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/elegant-python-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-snake-case)